# Get text with correct font from pptx with Openxml

Tags: c#, openxml

I use these methods to get the text:

```
public static string[] GetAllTextInSlide(SlidePart slidePart)
    {
        // Verify that the slide part exists.
        if (slidePart == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("slidePart");
        }

        // Create a new linked list of strings.
        LinkedList<string> texts = new LinkedList<string>();

        // If the slide exists...
        if (slidePart.Slide != null)
        {
            // Iterate through all the paragraphs in the slide.
            foreach (var paragraph in slidePart.Slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Paragraph>())
            {
                // Create a new string builder.                    
                StringBuilder paragraphText = new StringBuilder();

                // Iterate through the lines of the paragraph.
                foreach (var text in paragraph.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text>())
                {
                    // Append each line to the previous lines.
                    paragraphText.Append(text.Text);
                }

                if (paragraphText.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Add each paragraph to the linked list.
                    texts.AddLast(paragraphText.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        if (texts.Count > 0)
        {
            // Return an array of strings.
            return texts.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and

```
public static string[] GetAllTextInSlide(PresentationDocument presentationDocument, int slideIndex)
    {
        // Verify that the presentation document exists.
        if (presentationDocument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("presentationDocument");
        }

        // Verify that the slide index is not out of range.
        if (slideIndex < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("slideIndex");
        }

        // Get the presentation part of the presentation document.
        PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

        // Verify that the presentation part and presentation exist.
        if (presentationPart != null && presentationPart.Presentation != null)
        {
            // Get the Presentation object from the presentation part.
            Presentation presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;

            // Verify that the slide ID list exists.
            if (presentation.SlideIdList != null)
            {
                // Get the collection of slide IDs from the slide ID list.
                var slideIds = presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements;

                // If the slide ID is in range...
                if (slideIndex < slideIds.Count)
                {
                    // Get the relationship ID of the slide.
                    string slidePartRelationshipId = (slideIds[slideIndex] as SlideId).RelationshipId;

                    // Get the specified slide part from the relationship ID.
                    SlidePart slidePart = (SlidePart)presentationPart.GetPartById(slidePartRelationshipId);

                    // Pass the slide part to the next method, and then return the array of strings that method returns to the previous method.
                    return GetAllTextInSlide(slidePart);
                }
            }
        }
        // Else, return null.
        return null;
    }
```

but they just give me the words. How can I get the text with the correct font and color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;


namespace OpenXmlGetPowerpointTextInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PresentationDocument myPres = PresentationDocument.Open(@"test.pptx", true))
            {
                PresentationPart presPart = myPres.PresentationPart;
                //SlidePart slide = presPart.GetPartsOfType<SlidePart>().FirstOrDefault();
                SlidePart[] slidePartList = presPart.SlideParts.ToArray();
                foreach (SlidePart part in slidePartList)
                {
                    RunProperties[] runProList = part.Slide.Descendants<RunProperties>().ToArray();
                    foreach (RunProperties r in runProList)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(r.FontSize.Value);
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```